# Can audio played during REM sleep improve recall?

Tags: sleep, memory, learning

I was reading about [sleep-learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep-learning) - for example of the type depicted in The Simpsons episode, [Bart's Friend Falls in Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bart%27s_Friend_Falls_in_Love):

> Homer orders a subliminal cassette tape to help him lose weight, but is accidentally sent one that helps him increase his vocabulary after the weight-loss tapes sell out. [...] Homer puts on the headphones in bed and falls asleep. When he wakes up, he is suddenly articulate.

I found [some](http://www.audiolibrosgratis.org/2009/09/aprende-ingles-mientras-duermes.html) [articles](http://www.elconfidencial.com/alma-corazon-vida/2014-10-29/tres-cosas-que-puedes-aprender-mientras-duermes-segun-la-ciencia_419253/) *(in Spanish)* and other references (including an article in the [Oxford Journal](http://cercor.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2014/06/23/cercor.bhu139.short)) about how such method improves memory recall *just* by listening to audio material during the REM (Rapid-Eye Movement) phase of sleep.

I'm wondering if such learning methods are effective.